# SQL Query For Loop in Pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a SQL query that is expected to return over 5 million rows. I'm trying to use pandas to split the results into separate Excel workbooks (or worksheets within a single workbook if possible). I believe that due to the size, I will need to incorporate a for loop and chunking. Here is a snapshot of my current code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


filepath = r'C:\Path\Keylist.csv'
key = pd.read_csv(filepath)
keylist = key['column'].tolist()

#Define connection string
cnxn=pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes',
                    driver='{SQL Server}',
                    server='abc',
                    database='xyz')

#Define query
query="""SELECT 
[A]
,[B]
FROM [xyz].[table] (NOLOCK)
WHERE [A] in ('%s') AND [B] in ('VALUE')""" % ("','".join(keylist))  

#Save pd df to excel
df = pd.read_sql(query,cnxn)
df.to_excel(r'J:\Path\Report.xlsx', index = False)
```

In regards to the keylist variable, it is a list that can be up to 300,000 strings. An answer was provided to this by passing the strings into a JSON document and parsing them on the server but even with the provided example I could not wrap my head around how to apply it to this scenario.

Comment: I feel like a better approach for your keylist issue (or maybe just different) is to push the keylist into a temporary table on sql server and then do your `WHERE [A] IN (SELECT column FROM keylist_temp_table) AND [B] in ('VALUE');`

Comment: `NOLOCK` is not a "go-faster" switch, it's a "incorrect-results" switch. Stop splattering it everywhere. Looks like you need a Table Valued Parameter here.